# how to sqlite query to core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

how can i translate the following sqlite query to core data

```
select name, firstname, class, telephone, entryDateTime, counselor, count() 
  from myTable 
  group by strftime('yy-mm-dd', entryDateTime), name, class, counselor 
  order by entryDateTime desc;
```

[what did i try?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942957/group-by-date-yyyy-mm-dd-with-nsfetchrequest)

i want to group by date(yy-mm-dd), class, counselor, and name. entryDateTime is in UTC but it should be converted to local time.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible method for "group by"-like queries is the `NSFetchedResultsController`. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16920548/427083) of a couple of days ago, which should help you.

To solve the problem of subgrouping based on more than one attribute, you just use the `sectionNameKeyPath` as a subgroup and do the other grouping from there after fetching.

Alternatively, consider putting the attributes you need into a different entity and group by that entity.

Comment: i saw your answer already. i need to group on more than one attribute and use count aggregate. i wont be using sections. but i should count and group by more than one attribute and sort desc on date(yy-mm-dd). how can i achieve that with nsfetchcontroller?

Comment: You could group by the first attribute (the date) and then deal with the subgrouping when you need it. I am also suggesting another alternative in my edited answer.

Comment: well i was thinking about sectionNameKeyPath for date with transient property for yy-mm-dd. but i wonder how to group and count other attributes on that result. any clue?

Comment: One interesting avenue is to explore the option of using `NSDictionaryResultType` for your fetch request and trying to tweak the predicate with the request's `propertiesToGroupBy` attribute. Get ready for `NSExpression`, `NSExpressionDescription` and similarly verbose APIs.

Comment: if you have checked the link in my question. i was on that path. converting date from utc to local prevented the whole process.